# My app crashes when I try to log sign up a user and enable push notifications through parse

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm trying to enable push notifications through parse. The parse notification code works if there is already a user cached and signed into the app. If I logout and try to signup a new user, however, the app crashes and I get an error that states: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'...I believe the issue is with the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method within the app delegate. Because there isn't a currentUser logged in, when the app tries creating a PFInstallation, all of the associating fields are returning nil. I have tried an if statement checking for a currentUser before running the PFInstallation code, but the app still crashes. I need to register for notifications after signup occurs, but I can't figure out how to do that seeing as didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken needs to occur in the app delegate. Any advice or solutions are appreciate. My code snippet is below. Thanks!

**EDIT: This code works now!**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil) 
    {
        currentInstallation[@"currentUser"]=[PFUser currentUser];
    }
    else 
    {
        [currentInstallation removeObjectForKey:@"currentUser"];
    }
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

}

**For Sending Push Notifications**

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
    [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.recipient.objectId];
    PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query];
    [query whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:userQuery];

    NSString *sendingUser = self.currentUser.username;

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@: \n %@", sendingUser,self.message.text];

    PFPush *push= [[PFPush alloc]init];
    [push setQuery:query];
    [push setMessage:message];
    [push sendPushInBackground];

    NSLog(@"Message sent!");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still register an installation without a current user, but you have to make sure that the user is removed from the registration -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil)
    {
        currentInstallation[@"currentUser"]=[PFUser currentUser];
    }
    else {
        [currentInstallation removeObjectForKey:@"currentUser"];
    }
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Then, wherever you handle login/logout events you can update the current installation record.  For example -

```
-(void) loggedIn
{  

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation=[PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    currentInstallation[@"currentUser"]=[PFUser currentUser];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}

-(void) notLoggedIn
{

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation=[PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation removeObjectForKey:@"currentUser"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the code, but unfortunately it's still not working. I'm still getting the 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.' exception.

Comment: Hmmm.  This is working code straight out of one of my projects.  If you are getting nil fields in your PFInstallation object perhaps you have a problem with your Parse API installation.  Try deleting your app from your device

Comment: I considered that. Like I said though, if I comment out the code, log into the app -caching the logged in user- and then uncomment the code and run the app with the logged in user, everything seems to work. I can even send notifications between two iphones. I've deleted the app as well and it doesn't help.

Comment: You should be able to just say `PFInstallation *i=[PFInstallation currentInstallation]; [i saveInBackground];` without getting an error

Comment: Which key on your `PFInstallation` is nil?  Set a breakpoint after you retrieve the current installation and examine PFObject->estimatedData in the debugger

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` looks like now?

Comment: Just edited it...the debugger keeps throwing a breakpoint on [PFObject setObject: forKey:] and then highlights some line of random characters in the stack.

Comment: Ok, I just deleted the app off of both iPhones and completely restarted xcode, and the code you posted worked. I'm testing it a few more times to make sure, but I think it may finally work. I have absolutely no idea what was going on though. Maybe just a bug in xcode? Regardless, thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Paulw11,I have one more question for you. The notifications stopped being sent between users. I haven't changed any of my code except for the PFInstallation problem I had earlier, but now the notifications are being sent to the server without any subscribers attached to them. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Your original code added the installation to a channel. I didn't include that in my code because it wasn't in my app. Is that important for your push code?

Comment: I didn't think it was because it was just a generic "global" channel. I'm trying to enable push notifications from user to user as opposed to a multi-person broadcast.

Comment: Before, I could select what user was selecting the message and subsequent notification, and it would work, but now it's just loading it onto the parse server without any "recipient" associated with the notification. Although my code for sending to a recipient hasn't changed.

Comment: You can check your push message history in the Parse dashboard - perhaps see what that shows. Also did you include the code to add the user to the PFInstallation after login?

Comment: Yes, I included the code after log in...The message history shows notifications being sent, but without 0 subscribers attributed to each notification. So i'm getting them to the server, but they're not going to the correct destination, or any destination for that matter.

Comment: I added the code for sending a notification to my post. If you wouldn't mind taking a look I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Your push query is searching for a match in the key "User", but my code sets "currentUser".  I suspect if you change it to `[query whereKey:@"currentUser" matchesQuery:userQuery];` it will work again

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid. I can not believe I kept looking that. I have been staring at this for 3+ hours trying to get it to work. Thank you so so so so much! I wish there was something like Reddit gold that I could give you for you help, haha. LIFE SAVER!